# What is the meaning of %()s in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting, string-interpolation

I see like this `%(asctime)s` in the logging module

What is the meaning of `%()s` instead of `%s`?

I only know `%s` means "string" and I can't find other information about `%()s` on the internet.

Comment: Its a formating syntax for string..please refer internet for this....eg: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a string formatting feature when using the [`%` form of Python string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) to insert values into a string. The case you're looking at allows named values to be taken from a dictionary by providing the dictionary and specifying keys into that dictionary in the format string.  Here's an example:

```
values = {'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'California'}
s = "I live in %(city)s, %(state)s" % values
print(s)
```

Result:

```
I live in San Francisco, California
```

Answer (score 8):

`%(asctime)s` is a placeholder used by the logging module to get the `'asctime'` [attribute of a `LogRecord` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes).

The [notation `'%(key)s'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) is used to identify a key within a mapping and insert its value in a format string. For example, consider a person named john who is 168 cm tall and weighs 72 kilos.

```
person = {'name': 'john', 'height': 168, 'weight': 72}
```

If you wanted to print their name and weight, you wouldn't need to specify each instance that is inserted nor would you need to account for the fact that the weight is an int. All you need to do is specify the keys you want (within the `%()s` specifiers) and supply the mapping where those items are stored after the `%`.

```
>>> print('%(name)s, %(weight)s' % person)
john, 72
```

This method of string formatting is similar to [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> print('{name}, {weight}'.format(**person))
john, 72
```

Comment: I edited this answer cause a bunch of terminology and other details were wrong. To start, `%(asctime)s` is a *format specifier*, not a [`Formatter` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects), and it doesn't do the conversion itself, the string it's inside does. As well, there was a link to an obsolete version of the documentation. You can check the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63862749/revisions) to see exactly what was changed.

Comment: Taylr, since you're new, I want to add that SO is sort of like a wiki, where people can [improve other people's content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), but as the author, you can always [edit] your own posts. You can take my edits as you like, even revert them if you want. And for context, most edits aren't as drastic as this, but I didn't want to just downvote and tell you you're wrong, since you made some good points.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks a lot for the edits! I appreciate it!

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for a way to format a nested dict using `%()s`. Does anyone know if it's possible? e.g. `test_dic = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 1}}`. What if I want to format a string with the value of the key `c` from the nested dict? I tried something like `s_formatted = "Value of c is: %(b['c'])s % test_dic"`, but without success.. Thanks!

Comment: @benmaq if you have been using the string you showed above: 
```s_formatted = "Value of c is: %(b['c'])s % test_dic"``` then you need to move the ```% test dic``` out of the string. The result should be ```s_formatted = "Value of c is: %(b['c'])s" % test_dic```

Comment: Your solution does not work though :/ Even after removing `test_dic` from the string (which was a mistake on my end)